# Add char to a String and delete the char array

Tags: c++

Is adding a `char` from a `char*` to a `std::string` and then `delete[]` the char array can cause UB?

or is it safe to process the string after the `delete[]` ?

```
int buffer_size = 4096;
char* buffer = new char[buffer_size];

//here there was removed code that assign values to the buffer[i]    

std::string data;

for (int i = 0; i < buffer_size ; i++)
{
    data.push_back(buffer[i]);
}

delete[] buffer;

//is the data string content secured at this point?
```

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of the push_back function is

```
void push_back( CharT ch );
```

As the parameter ch is passed by value and not by reference, it is copied into the string, therefore deleting the source of the char you appended to the string does not cause any issues.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting after creating the string is fine as `push_back` copies the data. However, a better method is to use simply:

```
std::string data(buffer, buffer_size);
```

Calling `push_back` in a loop may trigger memory allocation multiple times. But with the constructor whole `buffer_size` memory is allocated at once.

Answer (score 3):

It's safe. But you may also use std::string::append(const char*s , size_t n);

Answer (score 3):

You can see from the signature of [std::string::push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back)

> ```
>  void push_back( CharT ch );
> ```

that the function argument is copied. Hence, deleting any resource that owned the `char` after it has been *copied*  into some string is fine.

Note that you can also avoid the manual looping by

```
data.insert(data.end(), buffer, buffer + buffer_size);
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, its fine, cause you copy chars from buffer to data, so there is no link between two variables after copy is completed. Also you should consider more effective option to copy char* to string, for example this one http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/